# Phonegap/Cordova and angular performance

Tags: angularjs, cordova

Im working on a project that involves an angular site, inside a phonegap/cordova application.
I dont have any expensive operation on JS or angular, not any scope watch, just the very basic angular bindings. An is really, really slow. Any tip about how to improve performance for the application? Im testing on a real iPhone 5, so speed should not be an issue. Cordova v3.2 and Angular 1.2.3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest thing to consider is that AngularJS has a large amount of compilation and scope management to do to handle your app.  These are very CPU intensive operations.

Desktop PC's have the advantage of (relatively) massive reserves of CPU performance and highly optimized JavaScript engines.

In a CPU contstrained application (like an AgularJS app) a mobile browser is going to have a very difficult time compiling and handling scopes.

Here's a quick read from KendoUI highlighting [real-world JavaScript performance on mobile devices](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/11-10-07/javascript_performance_on_mobile_devices.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps some code sample of what you're doing could help answering the question better, I'm not sure exactly what's going on in your app. But that said, you should checkout onsenUI (built on top of angular and uses topcoat), checkout the sample app on github https://github.com/malikov/simple-angular-phonegap-app to get an idea of how to create the app, I had to comment out a line of their library which was crashing my app (had a maximum stack size error somehow). Overall it runs pretty smoothly and there's no glitches, using angular, give it a try and let me know :)